# variable assignment doesn't work javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, double, equals

In the following code, the console.log from the line 92 and 93 (switchPosition function) doesn't provide the same result. I am, I have to admit, stuck.

Any thoughts, ideas, explanations?

Thanks you for the time taken,

```
var Carrousel = (function () {
    var self = {},
            config = {
                item: 3, // item to be displayed
                scroll: 2 // number of items to be scrolled
            },
    container = null,
            items = null,
            nbItems = null,
            nbSlide = null,
            position = [],
            searchPositionDepending = []
            ;




    self.init = function (opts) {
        options = opts || {}

        execute();

    }

    // Private Method
    execute = function () {
        container = document.getElementById('carrousel');
        items = document.getElementsByClassName('flux');
        var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
        var containerHeight = items[0].offsetHeight * 1.5;
        container.style.height = '' + containerHeight + '';
        nbItems = document.getElementsByClassName('flux').length;
        nbSlide = nbItems / config.item;

        // Initialisation du Carrousel
        for (i = 0; i < nbItems; i++) {
            items[i].style.width = '' + (containerWidth / config.item) + '';
            items[i].style.display = 'none';
            items[i].style.position = 'absolute';
            items[i].style.top = "0";
            items[i].style.left = "0";
            items[i].setAttribute('data-position', '' + (i + 1) + '');
            items[i].setAttribute('data-number', '' + i + '');
        }

        searchPosition();
        placement();

        document.getElementById('next').onclick = function () {
            next();
            searchPosition();
            switchPosition();
            placement();
            // position();
        }
        document.getElementById('previous').onclick = function () {
            // previous();
            // searchPosition();
            // position();
        }
    }

    searchPosition = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < config.item; i++) {
            searchPositionDepending[i] = (function () {         //Appending a function searchPosition per item displayed
                for (j = 1; j <= config.item; j++) {            //Passing through the first items to get their position 
                    if (items[i].dataset.position === '' + j + '') {
                        position[j] = items[i];
                        return true;
                    } else {
                    }
                }
                ;
            })();
        }
    }

    switchPosition = function () {
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < nbItems; i++, j++) {
            if (items[i].dataset.position === '' + j + '') {
                position[i] = position[i];
            }
        }
        for (i = config.item, j = 1; i < nbItems; i++, j++) { //Replacing in good order, except for the one that are place into the variable position[];
            items[i] = items[j];
        }

        for (i = (nbItems - config.item +1), j = 1; i <= nbItems; i++, j++) { //Replacing in good order the one that are place into variable position[];
            items[i] = position[j];
            console.log(i);
            console.log(j);
            console.log(position[j]);
            console.log(items[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < nbItems; i++) {
            console.log(items[i]);
        }
        console.log(items[10]);

    }

    placement = function () {
        for (i = 1; i <= config.item; i++) {
            var rect = items[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            item_width = Math.floor(rect.width);
            item_height = Math.floor(rect.height);

            var x = item_width * (i - 1) * 1.1;

            items[i].style.display = 'block';
            items[i].style.transform = "translate3D(" + x + "px, 0px, 0px)";
        }
    }

    next = function () {

        for (i = config.item, j = 1; i < nbItems; i++, j++) { //Updating all dataset position, except for the items that are displayed. 
            items[i].dataset.position = j;
        }

        for (i = 1, j = 2; i <= config.item; i++, j--) {
            position[i].dataset.position = nbItems - j;
            position[i].style.display = "none";
        }

    }


    return self;

})();
```

Comment: That is a lot of code with no line numbers! Are you talking about `console.log(position[j]);` and `console.log(items[i]);` are not printing the same thing?

Comment: your functions will not private but global because they don't have var before variable names.

Comment: What is the point of this: `position[i] = position[i];` it does not make any logical changes.

Comment: Also missing a `;` in `options = opts || {}` in the `self.init' function.

Comment: @KoreanwGlasses other than consistency, adding the `;` will make no difference at all.

Comment: Yes, Why both console.log are not printing the same thing... since there is an assignment just on the top of the. I copied all my code, because I thought the error may have come from another part of the code.